# SolrCloud hash range set to null after recovery from index corruption

Tags: solr, lucene, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I have a SolrCloud set up with 12 shards with 2 replicas each, divided on 6 servers (each server hosting 4 cores). Solr version is 4.3.1.
Due to memory errors on one machine, 3 of its 4 indexes became corrupted. I unloaded the cores, repaired the indexes with the Lucene CheckIndex tool, and added the cores again.
Afterwards the SolrCloud hash range has been set to null for the shards with corrupt indexes (so new records can't be indexed to those shards).
Do anybody know how to set the range on the shards again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by uploading a new clusterstate.json to Zookeeper, using the Zookeeper CLI tool, with the correct hash ranges set (they were easily deducible since they were sorted by shard name).